# Durable subscriber with client-individual ACK not working

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp, consumer, jms-topic

I have a durable subscriber for a topic(eg:`topic_a`). I am trying to provide client-individual ACK. At the end of the try block, I am providing manual ack and in exception block, I am doing no acknowledgment. Whenever an error occurs the consumer(subscriber) is getting hung up and eventually stops.
I AM TRYING TO DO MANUAL ACK IN TOPIC(PUB-SUB) BASED IMPLEMENTATION.
1). Is it possible?
2). Whether the message will be redelivered to the same durable subscriber?

execute method inside main class:

```
        self.conn = stomp.Connection11(self.conn_param, encoding=self.ENCODE_FORMAT)
        self.conn.start()
        self.conn.connect(wait=True, headers={'client-id': self.CLIENT_ID})
        self.conn.set_listener('', CustomListener(self.conn))
```

Listener class:

```
class CustomListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn, func_to_exec):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        try:
            message = json.loads(message)

            /**DO SOME BUSINESS LOGIC**/

            self.conn.ack(headers.get("message-id"), int(headers.get("subscription")))
            print("message ack done..!")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Exception in processing message :: %s"%(ex))
```

in on_message Listener if any exception during process time. then the message needs to redelivered.

Answer (score 1):

If using client individual ack mode then your code has a responsibility to acknowledge the messages sent to it and if you fail to ack enough then the broker would stop sending you more because you've exhausted the available credit that is configured.  The broker would assume the unacknowledged messages are pending until you either ACK or NACK them.  You can use NACK to poison the message and either send it to DLQ or (if configured broker side redelivery) have the broker redeliver the message.